# Average of Averages?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence

Let's say I have covered a distance of d<sub>1</sub> on t<sub>1</sub>, d<sub>2</sub> on t<sub>2</sub>, d<sub>3</sub> on t<sub>3</sub> and d<sub>4</sub> on t<sub>4</sub>.

Please correct me if I am wrong. I guess...

Let s<sub>0</sub> =  0.

Avg. Speed(s<sub>1</sub>) after t<sub>1</sub> = (d<sub>1</sub>)/(t<sub>1</sub>)
Avg. Speed(s<sub>2</sub>) after t<sub>2</sub> = (d<sub>1</sub>+d<sub>2</sub>)/(t<sub>1</sub>+t<sub>2</sub>)
Avg. Speed(s<sub>3</sub>) after t<sub>3</sub> = (d<sub>1</sub>+d<sub>2</sub>+d<sub>3</sub>)/(t<sub>1</sub>+t<sub>2</sub>+t<sub>3</sub>)
Avg. Speed(s<sub>4</sub>) after t<sub>4</sub> = (d<sub>1</sub>+d<sub>2</sub>+d<sub>3</sub>+d<sub>4</sub>)/(t<sub>1</sub>+t<sub>2</sub>+t<sub>3</sub>+t<sub>4</sub>)

Acceleration(a<sub>1</sub>) after t<sub>1</sub> = (s<sub>1</sub>-s<sub>0</sub>)/(t<sub>1</sub>-t<sub>0</sub>)
Acceleration(a<sub>2</sub>) after t<sub>2</sub> = (s<sub>2</sub>-s<sub>0</sub>)/(t<sub>2</sub>-t<sub>0</sub>)
Acceleration(a<sub>3</sub>) after t<sub>3</sub> = (s<sub>3</sub>-s<sub>0</sub>)/(t<sub>3</sub>-t<sub>0</sub>)
Acceleration(a<sub>4</sub>) after t<sub>4</sub> = (s<sub>4</sub>-s<sub>0</sub>)/(t<sub>4</sub>-t<sub>0</sub>)

Would I get anything of value if I try to find the Avg of all Accelerations(a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, a<sub>4</sub>)?

If yes, can anyone please share more details on what it signifies and some details around that metric?

If not, please note that I'm trying to find the Average push I'm achieving, i.e. overview(avg) of the improvements I'm making. I assume, a constant higher acceleration(higher avg) implies a lot more distance covered. This is a try on getting one number to understand progress in a good manner.

P.S. I could be completely wrong(or partially). In that case please let me know and I can remove this post.

Thanks.

Comment: In general, if you have, for the $i$th interval, some consumption $x_i$ over time $t_i$, yielding an average rate $r_i = x_i/t_i$, one can't determine the overall average rate of consumption over all intervals $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ from just the individual averages $r_i$—at least, not without some further assumptions about the parameters. I suspect the average of averages in the unconstrained case doesn't have any more precise name than "average of averages."